# Standalone Trac (tracd) woes

Tags: linux, trac

I have installed and configured trac and it runs fine using the standalone **tracd** command. The problem is this: when I exit the terminal it suddenly terminates. I have tried:

- CTRL+Z, **bg**: now tracd runs but does not respond after I exit the terminal. the process is still there.
- I have tried **setsid tracd ...**. Same thing, the process runs but no response from the server after closing the terminal

Do you have any experience with tracd?

*I know I can solve the problem by setting up trac the canonical way using apache, I just don't want to. Using tracd would be perfectly fine for me. So please don't give me alternative solutions.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

run tracd either in screen, or run

```
nohup tracd&
```

And it'll continue to run after you close the terminal.

In the long run, you'll probably want to add it to your init scripts or something however.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the script I use to start tracd

```
#!/bin/sh

# ./startTrac.sh
/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/tracd \
  --auth *,/web/trac/trac.htdigest,Trac \
  --env-parent-dir /web/trac/htdocs \
  -d --port 81
```

It's the -d on the last line that sets it to run as a 'daemon', and put itself into the background. This won't start it running after the machine has restarted, but this is just from a home server that only I'm using, and it's only been restarted a few times in the last year anyway.

The `--auth *` refers to a number of Trac installations in the same directory as the script BTW. A little index.php, also in the same directory (here, `/web/trac/htdocs/`), just dumps a list out with links to http://URL/subdirname/